# Regex match string by one delimiter, and then another

Tags: regex

im struggling to find an regex which will do what I need.

I just want to first split the following by each pipe, and then split that match be each colon.

> partx_registration:DL66 LNH|test:value|test2:helloworld

So I would be left with 3 groups, and 2 values within them 2 groups.

Currently got the following:

```
/([^|]+)/g
```

However not too sure on how I would go about doing the second check.

Edit:

Using PHP, and I would expect:

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
   0:
   (2) ["partx_registration", "DL66 LNH"]
   1:
   (2) ["test", "value"]
```

Edit 2:

The following code:

```
preg_match_all("~([^|:]+):([^|:]+)~", "partx_registration:DL66 LNH|test:value|test2:helloworld", $post_array);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($post_array);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "partx_registration:DL66 LNH"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "test:value"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "test2:helloworld"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "partx_registration"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "test"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "test2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "DL66 LNH"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "value"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "helloworld"
  }
}
```

This isn't the case on regex101 :S

Comment: `[^|:]+` .............

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's okay, but it makes 6 groups, rather than 3 groups.

Comment: Please also add the language that you are using for this task. Note it is easier to just split the strings with `|` and then with `:`. Also, you may try [`([^|:]+):([^|:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/JzNM0K/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is exactly what i'm after! Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `regex` for such a simple task. Split the initial string by `|` then each piece by `:` and you're almost there. All you need is [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). And the resulting code is more clear than using `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~([^|:]+):([^|:]+)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzNM0K/1)

**Details**

- `([^|:]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `|` and `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `([^|:]+)` - Group 2: any one or more chars other than `|` and `:`

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/doutgZ):

```
$str = 'partx_registration:DL66 LNH|test:value|test2:helloworld';
preg_match_all('/([^|:]+):([^|:]+)/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => partx_registration:DL66 LNH
            [1] => partx_registration
            [2] => DL66 LNH
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test:value
            [1] => test
            [2] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test2:helloworld
            [1] => test2
            [2] => helloworld
        )
)
```

Comment: If the keys are expected to be unique, you may use [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/R0wwCZ).

Comment: @MartynBall: [Regex101.com generates the code for you](https://regex101.com/r/JzNM0K/1/codegen?language=php). See [this demo in PHP](https://ideone.com/doutgZ).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `regex` for such a simple task. Split the initial string by `|` then each piece by `:` and you're almost there. All you need is [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). And the resulting code is more clear than using `regex`.

```
$input = 'partx_registration:DL66 LNH|test:value|test2:helloworld';

$output = array();
foreach (explode('|', $input) as $piece) {
    $output[] = explode(':', $piece);
}
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => partx_registration
            [1] => DL66 LNH
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test2
            [1] => helloworld
        )
)
```